# How can I sum with partial parts of cells, when there are empty cells?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a range of data. Each cell contains a number and some text like this,

> 1*100KVA.

Now I want to sum the numbers before * . I have found functions like this one:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(1*(LEFT(V2:V30;FIND("*";V2:V30)-1)))
```

and this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((VALUE(LEFT(V2:V30;FIND("*";V2:V30)-1))))
```

but they don't work, **when** there are empty cells in the range.

is there any solution?

Comment: =SUMPRODUCT(0+LEFT(A2:A5&"0*",FIND("*",A2:A5&"0*")-1))

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR(VALUE(LEFT(V2:V30;FIND("*";V2:V30)-1));0))
```

If you do not use Microsoft365 enter the formula with [CTRL]+[SHIFT]+[ENTER]

Here an example for Region A2:A5

[image]

Comment: Maybe in your region you have to replace semmicolon with comma?

Comment: than you should show some of your data, the above function works correct for your example.

Comment: don't know why but it doesn't work for me! @Chris. with my original formulas, in formula evaluation I reach this point sumproduct(({1;2;#value!;3})) and wonder how to exclude #value! from the last summation

Comment: Please show your formula, it seams the IFERROR() is not "working"

Comment: =SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR(VALUE(LEFT(A2:A5;FIND("*";A2:A5)-1));0)) returns 1!

=SUMPRODUCT((VALUE(LEFT(A2:A5;FIND("*";A2:A5)-1)))) returns #value!

Comment: Are you using it as an array formula? By pressing CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER. You must put the formula in the cell and use CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER to make it an array formula, otherwise it only evaluates the first cell in the range.

Comment: Or is there as SPACE between the fist value and then *

Comment: It needs to be an array formula

Comment: strange thing! the result of the function =SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR(VALUE(LEFT(A2:A5;FIND("";A2:A5)-1));0)) changes when I move formula to other cells. in front of 1*100 (c2 in Chris pic it returns 1, in front of 2*100 it returns 2 and so on

Comment: thanks @jamheadart it worked. now is there a solution without using arrays? anyway thanks you all

Comment: If the answer was helpful and solves your problem, maybe you can set the question as answered and vote the answer... best regards chris

Answer (score 0):

A workaround non-array formula

Maybe by adding "`0*`" behind the data, and the formula become >>

```
=SUMPRODUCT(0+LEFT(A2:A5&"0*",FIND("*",A2:A5&"0*")-1))
```

Note : to replace comma with semicolon to suit with your regional setting